# error 404-How to view PDF after upload in Laravel 7

Tags: php, html, laravel, file-upload

I want to have a button where a client can view an applicant's document that the candidate has uploaded, but for some reason I cannot figure out why it doesn't work.

It was working fine offline, but I deployed the site via FTP today and It doesn't want to work.

I am less than a junior developer so please be kind about messy code,

Here is my code for

upload blade:

```
    <form action="{{route('cover.letter')}}" method="POST" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">@csrf
 <div class="card">
 <div class="card-header">Update Cover Letter</div>
 <div class="card-body">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="cover_letter"><br>
 <button class="btn btn-success float-right" 
 type="submit">Update</button>
                             </div>
                          </div>
```

Code for route:

```
Route::post('user/cv','UserController@cv')->name('cv');
```

Code for Controller:

```
  public function cv(Request $request){
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $cv = $request->file('cv')->store(public_path('storage/files'));
    Profile::where('user_id',$user_id)->update(['cv'=>$cv]);
    
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'CV Successfully Updated!');}
```

Code for viewing the CV :

```
@if(!empty($profile->cv))
    <a href="{{Storage::url($profile->cv)}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">View my CV</a>
@else
    <p> </p>
@endif
```

When I click the button I get this url:

https://www.cvroad.co.za/storage/home/cvroazdi/cvapp/public/storage/files/p0WGFGYeir8ltvZEfjPqY9jB5jKTLdYC9437ZVG.pdf

but still 404 not found?

Do I need to create a symlink or something? -

I tried creating one earlier trying to piece together what I see on tutorials and I made one called symlinkcreate.php

```
<?php
```

symlink ('home/cvroazdi/cvapp/storage/app/public','/home/cvroazdi/public_html/storage/files');

I paste it in the public_html directory and run it.

Any and all help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Normally you could run `php artisan storage:link` to symlink `storage/public` to your `public folder. However I think it is not a smart idea to do that for this feature. Since everybody can (should be able to) access your public folder. Suggestion is too look into [file download](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#file-downloads) responses. Create a controller where you check if the user is allowed and return the file (which is not available in public folder).

Comment: @thomasvanderveen thank you, I am still trying to figure this out with that method in mind.